# How do I submit a copyright infringement notification to the various MSN sites?

Tags: copyright

I uploaded a video to YouTube which has become moderately viral. Unfortunately part of this experience has involved filing copyright infringement notifications with various video sites all over the internet. Somewhat surprisingly I have had the most difficulty with figuring out how to file notices with the various MSN brands: uk.msn.com br.msn.com ca.msn.com mx.msn.com xin.msn.com in.msn.com etc.

Is there a single form or email address that can be used to file copyright infringement notifications across all of the MSN sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Microsoft considers MSN to be a service. When I read the fine print on the [notices of infringement page for Microsoft services MSN](https://www.microsoft.com/info/FormForCloud.aspx) is listed:

> This form is for reporting copyright or trademark infringements for
>   any Microsoft service, such as MSN, Hotmail, Windows Live, Windows
>   Azure, SkyDrive, Zune, Messenger or Xbox. This form is not for
>   reporting infringements relating to Search or Applications.